# How to create a table in Android with multiple columns?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablelayout

I want to create a table in android with multiple column. Most of the examples I saw is with 2 columns. (I am new to Java and Android.) I need 3-4 columns and I should be able to add the rows dynamically in the table. Can anyone provide me a sample code.  (I am using eclipse in win 7)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a TableLayout view and not a table in a database??

If so, here's an XML example of a table with three columns and three rows.

Each < TableRow > element creates a row in the table, and each view inside the  element creates a "column". I've used TextViews, but they can be ImageViews, EditText, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id = "@+id/RHE"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="0"
         android:padding="5dp">

     <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/runLabel"
             android:text="R"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/hitLabel"
             android:text="H"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/errorLabel"
             android:text="E"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
     </TableRow>

     <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/visitorRuns"
             android:text="0"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/visitorHits"
             android:text="0"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/visitorErrors"
             android:text="0"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
     </TableRow>

     <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/homeRuns"
             android:text="0"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/homeHits"
             android:text="0"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/homeErrors"
             android:text="0"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

To dynamically change these in the code, you'd have something like this:

```
// reference the table layout
TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.RHE);
// delcare a new row
TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
// add views to the row
newRow.addView(new TextView(this)); // you would actually want to set properties on this before adding it
// add the row to the table layout
tbl.addView(newRow);
```

Comment: Yes, I want a table layout view.The columns are not properly positioned. How to position the columns? How I can add the rows dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'not properly positioned'. The TableLayout will be sized according to its properties, as are the items inside. Perhaps if you posted your xml as well as what you hope to see, we'd have more ability to answer the question.

Comment: I used the code of xml file as it is . Just change the first 2 lines. i.e.     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id = "@+id/RHE"
It is showing a lot of error. What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: The style tags will throw you off. I just copied this portion out of one of my working projects, and I didn't notice that it referenced some style.xml attributes. I've taken them out of the example, and it should work fine if you copy/paste it now.